# Linking two lists based on a common value and

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python 2.7 and I want the 1st column as the key column in employees and it has to check on dept 1st column and generate results.

Employees comes from a text file and dept comes from a database. I tried a lot but didn't get an easy answer. What is wrong with my code?

```
**Inputs :**

employees=['1','peter','london']
employees=['2','conor','london']
employees=['3','ciara','london']
employees=['4','rix','london']

dept=['1','account']
dept=['2','developer']
dept=['3','hr']

**Expected Output :**

results=['1','peter','london','account']
results=['2','conor','london','developer']
results=['3','ciara','london','hr']
results=['4','rix','london',null]
```

Comment: you need dictionaries instead of lists, and you're redefining the lists at each line.

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried, and where you have problem that you're unable to solve.

Comment: Thanks guys..Jean's code helped me

Answer (score 0):

your input makes no sense. Each line overwrites the previous one data-wise. Here it seems that the digits (as string) are the keys, and some default action must be done when no info is found in `dept`.

To keep the spirit, just create 2 dictionaries, then use dictionary comprehension to generate the result:

```
employees = dict()
dept = dict()

employees['1'] = ['peter','london']
employees['2'] = ['conor','london']
employees['3'] = ['ciara','london']
employees['4'] = ['rix','london']

dept['1']=['account']
dept['2']=['developer']
dept['3']=['hr']

result = {k:v+dept.get(k,[None]) for k,v in employees.items()}

print(result)
```

which yields a dictionary with all the info. Note that `null` is `None` in python:

```
{'1': ['peter', 'london', 'account'], '4': ['rix', 'london', None], '3': ['ciara', 'london', 'hr'], '2': ['conor', 'london', 'developer']}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave a fair idea. My input was just to show how it looks from end user point of view. Still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a class. Consider this:

```
class Employee:
     def __init__(self, number, name, location, dept):
          self.number = str(number)
          self.name = name
          self.location = location
          self.dept = dept

     def data(self):
          return [self.number,
                  self.name,
                  self.location,
                  self.dept]

peter = Employee(1, 'peter', 'london', 'account')
print(peter.data())

['1', 'peter', 'london', 'account']
>>>
```